# Adobe Reader Broswer Plug-in - Issues with files greater than 2mb

Tags: pdf, acrobat, adobe-reader, web-optimization

I was wondering if anyone knew of any limitations with the Adobe Reader Browser plug-in. Currently I am experiencing issues when a visitor to my website is trying to open a PDF that is greater than 2mb in file size.

I have thought about how to go about optimising my pdf's even more than they currently are but an struggling to find the bst settings that give me a small file with graphics that are near print quality.

If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate them.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that a problem for one specific user?  Or is it repeatable?

It sounds like the user may have a messed up machine.  2MB is not all that big, so it should work fine.

There is a way (don't ask me how) to optimize a PDF for use on the web (Adobe refers to it as being serialized).  I'm pretty sure that's the default now though.

So either try serializing your PDFs, or try reinstalling Reader on the user's machine.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the reply, I didn't think 2mb was large, but wanted to check that the reader plugin didnt have some strange settings. I have had a play with the 'PDF optimizer' inside of acrobat pro, and that does get the file size down, just depends on the thoughts on how good the imagery looks.